# Cant able to install streamlit-webrtc package

Tags: python, webrtc, streamlit

when i try to install this package using this command(pip install -U streamlit-webrtc) iam a getting an error which i am not aware of that Please let me know how to resolve this issue

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

go to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ and install this. Then install the microsoft build tools(just check-mark it). After the installation of around 1.7gb, run the "pip install streamlit-webrtc" command. Installation will be completed.